# Automatic Date & Time update results in wrong time on Linux Machine

Tags: ntp, fedora-29

I am using Fedora 29, with kernel version 4.19.15-300 on my laptop.  It has been a while that I see the computer clock is about 6 to 7 minutes ahead.

Pondering why, I checked the status of `chronyd` (`systemctl status chronyd.service`) and I see the following log message repeated every time the machine is resumed from sleep:

```
chronyd[812]: Forward time jump detected!
```

Also, the output of `chronyc source` is an empty list.  Does this mean that there is a problem in the configuration of NTP on the machine, and that the time has never been actually synchronized?  Could anyone help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Is `chronyd` started? `service chronyd status` if not how about `ntpd`? This may be better asked over on [su] with a few more details since its not really a programming question

Comment: `chronyd` is active, but `ntpd` seems to be disabled `Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

I will ask the question on Super User as you suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: You should delete/migrate this question. Where does your time source come from? I'd say reset the time manually and run chronyd and see if it stays working or not.